# Go Slice - difference between [:n] and [n:]

Tags: arrays, go, slice

Go Slice question, please check below and comment if I am missing something.

```
   import "fmt"
   func main() {
       s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
       s = s[1:]
       fmt.Println(s)
       s = s[2:]
       fmt.Println(s)
       s = s[5:]
       fmt.Println(s)
  }
```

Output:

`[3 5 7 11 13]
[7 11 13]
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range`

The above makes sense.

```
func main() {
       s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
       s = s[:1]
       fmt.Println(s)
       s = s[:2]
       fmt.Println(s)
       s = s[:5]
       fmt.Println(s)
   }
```

Output:

`[2]
[2 3]
[2 3 5 7 11]`

Should this also get array out of bounds panic from s=s[:2]?

Comment: my question is w.r.t assignment, when we do s=s[:n], my thinking was s is getting overwritten by the new slice where in the old array\slice is actually lost, no longer exists. But to contrary I continue to slice on the original array that was already sliced and diced down, which seems different from Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subslicing in Go allows you to slice beyond the end of the slice, as long as it's still within range of the underlaying array's capacity.  You cannot slice *before* the start of that slice, but you can slice after it so long as you don't go past that last allocated index.

As an example, `s[3:]` then `s[:3]` works, but `s[4:]` then `s[:4]` will panic, as you're requesting indexes 4 through 7 of the underlying array, which only has allocated indexes 0-5.

It's a bit of an oddity, but it does allow you to max out any slice simply by doing `slice = slice[:cap(slice)]`.

https://play.golang.org/p/Gq5xoXc3Vd

The [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) annotes this, btw.  I've paraphrased it below for the simple slice notation you're using (there's an alternative that also specifies the maximum index for the new slice).

> For a string, array, pointer to array, or slice a, the primary expression `a[low : high]` constructs a substring or slice.
>   The indices are in range if 0 <= low <= high <= cap(a),
>   otherwise they are out of range.

Comment: Thanks, my question is w.r.t assignment, when we do s=s[:n], my thinking was s is getting overwritten by the new slice where in the old array\slice is actually lost. It seems a little non-intuitive to me.

Comment: Ah, no, same underlying array.  A slice, fundamentally, is just a 3-word structure, with a pointer to an underlying array, an integer length, and an integer capacity.  When you subslice, you alter that slice "header" (or create a new one) with updated fields as needed.  When you do `s=s[:n]`, all that does is change the "length" value of the slice header to `n`.  Still points to the same underlying array, still has the same capacity, so you can extend it again up to that capacity.

Comment: If you want to make a copy of the underlying array (ie. have a new slice that points to an entirely different array, but with the same data in it), you either need to do it manually, index by index, or use the built in [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) function, which does a deep copy of the slice. **Edit:** only deep copy to the array level.  If your array stores pointers, those won't be deep copied.

Comment: Thanks this makes it clear, Ok the key here seems capacity. So capacity and length is different in Go arrays. So when I slice it is better to loop over length than capacity, is that a true statement?

Comment: Oh ok ... copy() to make a duplicate

Comment: Yes, capacity just specifies the total size, relative to the array pointer, of the underlying array.  Length represents how much data is actually stored in it. You always want to loop over length, not capacity, as accessing an index of a slice that's inside the capacity but outside the length is still illegal.  The capacity can be longer than the length to allow `append()` and similar to grow the slice exponentially rather than reallocating for every append, allowing it to be amortized O(1) time for append.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to share my thoughts on this after reading the official blog:  https://blog.golang.org/slices

Here is the sliceHeader in Golang's blog:

```
type sliceHeader struct {
    Length        int
    ZerothElement *byte
}
```

Now you declare your slice:

```
s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
```

which I believe does something like:

```
var array [6]int
slice := sliceHeader {
    Length:        6,
    ZerothElement: &array[0], 
}
```

By doing: `s = s[:2]`, you effectively changed the Length of the sliceHeader from 6 to 2, so your sliceHeader will look like this:

```
slice := sliceHeader {
    Length:        2,
    ZerothElement: &array[0],
}
```

Notice that the ZerothElement is still pointing to the same place in memory. So we can extend the slice back to its original form `s = s[:6]` by simply changing the Length again.

Now, let's say you did not do `s = s[:2]` and instead did `s = s[2:]`, what you have effectively done is hiding the first two elements by subtracting 2 from Length AND shifting the ZerothElement two indices forward, resulting in a sliceHeader of:

```
slice := sliceHeader {
    Length:        4,
    ZerothElement: &array[2],   
}
```

At this point, you CANNOT restore the slice to its original form because there is no way to extend the slice beyond the ZerothElement. Okay, what if hypothetically you could access whatever elements before the ZerothElement? Then our slice becomes undefined because it could be `array[0...4]`, `array[1...5]`, or `array[2...6]`.

So yeah, that is why I think [n:] and [:n] behaves differently.